# Got “KeyError: <flask.cli.ScriptInfo object at 0x00000191FA23ABA8>” when running “heroku local:run flask deploy”

Tags: python, heroku, flask

Learning from *Flask Web Development* 17.4.2 and using Heroku local test, the following errors occurred when executing `heroku local: run flask` deployment:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KodX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\KodX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "F:\flasky\venv\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "f:\flasky\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 894, in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "f:\flasky\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 557, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "f:\flasky\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "f:\flasky\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1132, in invoke
    cmd_name, cmd, args = self.resolve_command(ctx, args)
  File "f:\flasky\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1171, in resolve_command
    cmd = self.get_command(ctx, cmd_name)
  File "f:\flasky\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 515, in get_command
    rv = info.load_app().cli.get_command(ctx, name)
  File "f:\flasky\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 377, in load_app
    raise_if_not_found=False)
  File "f:\flasky\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 254, in locate_app
    return find_best_app(script_info, module)
  File "f:\flasky\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 76, in find_best_app
    app = call_factory(script_info, app_factory)
  File "f:\flasky\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 114, in call_factory
    return app_factory(script_info)
  File "F:\flasky\app\__init__.py", line 22, in create_app
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
KeyError: <flask.cli.ScriptInfo object at 0x00000191FA23ABA8>
```

`__init__.py`

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_moment import Moment
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_pagedown import PageDown
from config import config

bootstrap = Bootstrap()
mail = Mail()
moment = Moment()
db = SQLAlchemy()
pagedown = PageDown()

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    moment.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    pagedown.init_app(app)

    if app.config['SSL_REDIRECT']:
        from flask_sslify import SSLify
        sslify = SSLify(app)

    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint, url_prefix='/auth')

    from .api import api as api_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint, url_prefix='/api/v1')

    return app
```

Environment version Details

```
Operating System: Windows 10
Python:3.7
Flask: 1.0.2
```

Reference books

> *Flask Web Development Version 2* 17.4.2 uses Heroku local test

Heroku CLI has a local command that tests applications locally in environments very close to Heroku servers. However, when running applications locally, environment variables such as FLASK_APP are no longer environment variables. The heroku local command looks for the environment variables that configure the application in the. env file in the top directory of the application. For example, the. env file may contain the following variables:

```
FLASK_APP=flasky.py
FLASK_CONFIG=heroku
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
```

Since the. env file contains passwords and other sensitive account information, do not include it in version control.

Deployment tasks and database creation are performed before starting the application. One-time tasks can be run using the local: run command:

```
(venv) $heroku local: run flask deploy    
[OKAY] Loaded ENV.env File as KEY = VALUE Format    
INFO Context impl SQLiteImpl.    
INFO Will assume non-transactional DDL.    
INFO Running upgrade - > 38c4e85512a9, initial migration    
INFO Running upgrade 38c4e85512a9 - > 456a945560f6, login support    
INFO Running upgrade 456a945560f6 - > 190163627111, account confirmation    
INFO Running upgrade 190163627111 - > 56ed7d33de8d, user roles    
INFO Running upgrade 56ed7d33de8d - > d66f086b258, user information    
INFO Running upgrade d66f086b258 - > 198b0eebcf9, caching of avatar hashes    
INFO Running upgrade 198b0eebcf9 - > 1b966e7f4b9e, post model    
INFO Running upgrade 1b966e7f4b9e - > 288cd3dc5a8, rich text posts    
INFO Running upgrade 288cd3dc5a8 - > 2356a38169ea, followers    
INFO Running upgrade 2356a38169ea - > 51f5ccfba190, comments
```

Comment: I run in to the problem when the environment variables weren't being set in your case particularly `FLASK_APP=flasky.py`.
I'm not using heroku but check if your environment variables are being set properly.